# MS Access: select first occurrence within a group

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have some data on individuals in our database. I need to select each observation only once, but that selection needs to be of the earliest occurrence.

There are 2 identifiers for occurrence though, year, and quarter:

```
 CustID     | OrderYear | Quarter 
 0001       |  2012     |   3
 0001       |  2012     |   4
 0001       |  2013     |   1
 0002       |  2012     |   3
 0002       |  2012     |   4
 0003       |  2013     |   1
```

I need the select statement to grab it so that the output is:

```
 CustID     | OrderYear | Quarter 
 0001       |  2012     |   3
 0002       |  2012     |   3
 0003       |  2013     |   1
```

So, observations are grouped by customer ID, then by Order Year, then by Quarter. Does this make sense? Without quarter I can get it just fine, but I need quarter in order to go the next step of the analysis and when I do that my technique fails.

Without quarter, I could just use `First(orderYear)` in the select statement, group by `CustID`, and it works just fine (the dataset is sorted by CustID and then Year, and then Quarter in ascending order, so in this case the First() grabs the earliest occurrence

```
SELECT CustID, First(OrderYear)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY CustID
```

The added layer of quarter is throwing me off though.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not just add `First(Quarter)`?

Comment: I tried that and ended up grabbing the first quarter in each year for some reason, so the result (in my example) would include 0001 twice: 2012,3 and 2013,1. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `GROUP BY` to determine the minimum *OrderYear* for each *CustID*.  Then join that query back to the main table to filter the dataset to only those combinations.  Finally you can find the minimum *Quarter* for each *OrderYear/CustID* combination.

```sql
SELECT t.CustID, t.OrderYear, Min(t.Quarter)
FROM
    Table1 AS t
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT CustID, Min(OrderYear) AS MinOfOrderYear
        FROM Table1
        GROUP BY CustID
    ) AS sub
    ON
           t.CustID = sub.CustID
       AND t.OrderYear = sub.MinOfOrderYear
GROUP BY t.CustID, t.OrderYear;
```

Comment: Ah that's perfect, but I have no idea why that works! Why is it that joining to the subquery filters the dataset to only those combinations (i'm so sorry, my SQL knowledge is very slowly expanding and I guess I haven't reached this part yet!)

Comment: `INNER JOIN` means only matching rows from both data sources are returned.  So the subquery serves as a selector to identify which rows of `Table1` will be evaluated for the `GROUP BY` and therefore `Min(t.Quarter)`